# Mysql With Rollup did not run what I expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my example (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Win64 (x86_64))

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t_tt;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_tt SELECT 1 AS tid,'team 1' AS teamName,111 AS teamData;

INSERT INTO t_tt VALUES(2,'team 2',222);
INSERT INTO t_tt VALUES(3,'team 3',333);

SELECT
 tid,
 isnull(tid),
 IF(isnull(tid),'total',teamName) AS displayName,
 SUM(teamData)
FROM t_tt GROUP BY tid WITH ROLLUP;
```

And I think the result must be ：

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| tid | isnull(tid) | displayName | SUM(teamData) |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|   1 |       0     | team 1      |       111 |
|   2 |       0     | team 2      |       222 |
|   3 |       0     | team 3      |       333 |
|   3 |       1     | total       |       666 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Actually，the real answer is ：

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| tid | isnull(tid) | displayName | SUM(teamData) |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
|   1 |           0 | team 2      |           111 |
|   2 |           0 | team 3      |           222 |
|   3 |           0 | team 3      |           333 |
| NULL|           0 | team 3      |           666 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I dont know why the column of displayName is begins with "team 2" ,but not "team 1".

And the last row isnull(tid) should equals 1 , but not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a MySQL extension.  You have `teamName` in the `SELECT`, but it is not in the `GROUP BY`.  So, MySQL is free to take this value from any row.  To be honest, I thought it would need to be from a matching row.  I don't fully understand the behavior.

But, this is easy to fix.  One simple method is simply to add an aggregation function:

```
SELECT tid, tid is null,
       COALESCE(max(teamName), 'total') AS displayName,
       SUM(teamData)
FROM t_tt
GROUP BY tid WITH ROLLUP;
```

Note that for the additional row from the `ROLLUP`, the value is arbitrary.

I also found that the results were fixed if the table were pre-declared with a primary key:

```
CREATE  TABLE t_tt (
  tid int primary key,
  teamName varchar(255),
  teamData int
);

INSERT INTO t_tt VALUES(1, 'team 1', 111);
INSERT INTO t_tt VALUES(2, 'team 2', 222);
INSERT INTO t_tt VALUES(3, 'team 3', 333);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to process all the extra information out of the group query, since some columns not grouped could have an arbitrary value:

```
SELECT tid, 
   isnull(tid), 
   IF(isnull(tid),'total',teamName) AS displayName, 
   team_sum 
FROM
(
 SELECT
  tid,
  teamName,
  SUM(teamData) as team_sum
 FROM t_tt 
 GROUP BY tid WITH ROLLUP
) t
```

See this Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8871cc/9